No component found with scheme: ftp on Fuse 7.13 with Camel 2.23
I am upgrading Fuse bundles from 6.3 to 7.13. All the bundles are Spring-DM based with camel-context.xmls which is not supported in Fuse 7. After using "aries-blueprint-spring" feature the camel-contexts are treated as blueprint.xmls and the contexts are getting registered.
Few of the context routes are using ftp which is failing with below error. I have checked in fuse the camel-ftp features is installed by default. The fuse parent pom in my project has imported all the fuse and camel required dependencies, even I tried adding camel-ftp dependency separately still the ftp component issue is not resolved.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.fuse</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-fuse-parent</artifactId>
    <version>7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>

While starting the service , we could see the ftp component is discovered from camel-ftp with below logs, but not sure why they are not available for the route to use it.
While Starting the bundles:

DEBUG | FelixStartLevel      | o.a.c.i.o.Activator              | 84 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001 | Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/ftp in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-ftp
DEBUG | FelixStartLevel      | o.a.c.i.o.Activator              | 84 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001 | Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/ftps in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-ftp
DEBUG | FelixStartLevel      | o.a.c.i.o.Activator              | 84 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001 | Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/sftp in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-ftp

While routes are running:

DEBUG | o.a.c.s.SpringCamelContext       | 84 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001 | Using ComponentResolver: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponentResolver@8daadb3 to resolve component with name: ftp
DEBUG | o.a.c.u.ResolverHelper           | 84 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001 | Lookup Component with name ftp in registry. Found: null
DEBUG | o.a.c.u.ResolverHelper           | 84 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001 | Lookup Component with name ftp-component in registry. Found: null


org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: ftp://hostname:21/folder/{otherproperties}
due to: No component found with scheme: ftp
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:759) ~[!/:2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001]
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:80) ~[!/:2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001]

came-context.xml
  
               <route id="route1">
                <from id="ftpServer" uri="file://App/Data/Listener/?sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true&amp;runLoggingLevel=OFF"/>
                   <pollEnrich id="_pollEnrich1">
                       <simple>  !<-- { ftp:// host and params }--> </simple>
                   </pollEnrich>
                  <to id="fuseServer" uri="file://APP/Data/"/>
                   <log id="_log1" message="log msg"/>
               </route>

Active bundles
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
System Bundle
mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/org.apache.karaf.features.extension/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.jboss.fuse.modules.patch/patch-management/7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.services/org.apache.karaf.services.eventadmin/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.metatype/1.2.4
mvn:org.ops4j.pax.url/pax-url-aether/2.6.14
mvn:org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/2.4.0.redhat-00002
mvn:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-api/2.2.7
mvn:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-log4j2/2.2.7
mvn:org.osgi/org.osgi.util.function/1.2.0
mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.coordinator/1.0.2
mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.converter/1.0.14
mvn:org.osgi/org.osgi.util.promise/1.3.0
mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.configadmin/1.9.26
mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.configurator/1.0.16
mvn:org.apache.karaf.config/org.apache.karaf.config.core/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.configadmin.plugin.interpolation/1.2.6
mvn:org.apache.sling/org.apache.sling.commons.johnzon/1.2.14
mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.cm.json/1.0.6
mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.fileinstall/3.7.4
mvn:org.jboss.fuse.modules/fuse-credential-store-core/7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/org.apache.karaf.features.core/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.ops4j.pax.url/pax-url-wrap/2.6.14/jar/uber
mvn:org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk18on/1.78.1
mvn:org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk18on/1.78.1
mvn:org.bouncycastle/bcutil-jdk18on/1.78.1
mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.12.6.redhat-00001
mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.12.6.redhat-00001
mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.12.6.1-redhat-00004
mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.12.6.redhat-00001
mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.12.6.redhat-00001
mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-base/2.12.6.redhat-00001
mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/2.12.6.redhat-00001
mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/2.12.6.redhat-00001
mvn:com.fasterxml.woodstox/woodstox-core/5.2.1
mvn:com.google.guava/guava/20.0.0.redhat-1
mvn:com.google.guava/guava/27.1-jre
mvn:com.google.guava/failureaccess/1.0.1.redhat-00013
mvn:com.sun.activation/javax.activation/1.2.0
mvn:com.sun.istack/istack-commons-runtime/3.0.12.redhat-00001
mvn:com.sun.mail/javax.mail/1.6.2.redhat-00001
mvn:org.jboss.fuse.modules/fuse-pax-transx-tm-narayana/7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:io.dropwizard.metrics/metrics-core/3.2.6.redhat-00001
mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-log/2.0.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-log-osgi/2.0.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-osgi/2.0.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001/war
mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-osgi-jmx/2.0.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:io.swagger/swagger-annotations/1.6.2
mvn:io.swagger/swagger-core/1.6.2
mvn:io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-annotations/2.1.9
mvn:io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-core/2.1.9
mvn:io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-models/2.1.9
mvn:io.swagger/swagger-jaxrs/1.6.2
mvn:io.swagger/swagger-models/1.6.2
mvn:io.undertow/undertow-core/2.2.30.SP1-redhat-00001
mvn:io.undertow/undertow-servlet/2.2.30.SP1-redhat-00001
mvn:io.undertow/undertow-websockets-jsr/2.2.30.SP1-redhat-00001
mvn:jakarta.enterprise/jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api/2.0.2.redhat-00005
mvn:jakarta.interceptor/jakarta.interceptor-api/1.2.5.redhat-00003
mvn:jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api/4.0.4
mvn:org.javassist/javassist/3.27.0.GA-redhat-00001
mvn:javax.jms/javax.jms-api/2.0.1
mvn:javax.transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2
mvn:jakarta.websocket/jakarta.websocket-api/1.1.2
mvn:joda-time/joda-time/2.9.9.redhat-00002
mvn:net.i2p.crypto/eddsa/0.3.0.redhat-00001
mvn:net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/2.10.9.2
mvn:org.apache.aries.blueprint/org.apache.aries.blueprint.api/1.0.1
mvn:org.apache.aries.blueprint/org.apache.aries.blueprint.cm/1.3.2
mvn:org.apache.aries.blueprint/org.apache.aries.blueprint.core/1.10.3
mvn:org.apache.aries.blueprint/org.apache.aries.blueprint.core.compatibility/1.0.0
mvn:org.apache.aries.jmx/org.apache.aries.jmx.api/1.1.5
mvn:org.apache.aries.jmx/org.apache.aries.jmx.blueprint.api/1.2.0
mvn:org.apache.aries.jmx/org.apache.aries.jmx.blueprint.core/1.2.0
mvn:org.apache.aries.jmx/org.apache.aries.jmx.core/1.1.8
mvn:org.apache.aries.jmx/org.apache.aries.jmx.whiteboard/1.2.0
mvn:org.apache.aries.proxy/org.apache.aries.proxy/1.1.13
mvn:org.apache.aries.transaction/org.apache.aries.transaction.blueprint/1.1.1
mvn:org.apache.aries.transaction/org.apache.aries.transaction.blueprint/2.3.1
mvn:org.apache.aries/org.apache.aries.util/1.1.3
mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-blueprint/2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-commands-core/2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-csv/2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-cxf/2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-cxf-transport/2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-ftp/2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-http-common/2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-http4/2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-jaxb/2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-jdbc/2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-jetty-common/2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-jetty9/2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-jms/2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-mail/2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-openapi-java/2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-paxlogging/2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-rest-swagger/2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-servlet/2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-spring/2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-undertow/2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/camel-karaf-commands/2.23.2.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:commons-codec/commons-codec/1.16.1.redhat-00006
mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2/2.9.0
mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-pool2/2.11.1.redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-csv/1.6
mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.12.0.redhat-00001
mvn:commons-net/commons-net/3.6
mvn:commons-pool/commons-pool/1.6.0.redhat-10
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-core/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-bindings-coloc/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-bindings-corba/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-bindings-soap/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-bindings-xml/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-databinding-aegis/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-features-clustering/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-features-logging/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-features-metrics/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-features-throttling/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-js/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-simple/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-javascript/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-management/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-rs-client/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-rs-extension-search/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-rs-json-basic/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-rs-service-description/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-rs-service-description-common-openapi/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger-ui/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-security/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-security-saml/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-transports-http/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-transports-http-undertow/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-transports-jms/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-transports-local/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-transports-udp/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-ws-addr/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-ws-mex/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-ws-policy/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-ws-rm/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-ws-security/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-wsdl/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/cxf-karaf-commands/3.3.6.fuse-7_13_0-00015-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.cxf.xjc-utils/cxf-xjc-runtime/3.3.1.fuse-7_13_0-00008-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.scr/2.2.4
mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec/1.0.1.redhat-3
mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-osgi-registry/1.1
mvn:org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-osgi/4.5.13.redhat-00007
mvn:org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore-osgi/4.4.14
mvn:org.apache.karaf.bundle/org.apache.karaf.bundle.blueprintstate/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.bundle/org.apache.karaf.bundle.core/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.deployer/org.apache.karaf.deployer.blueprint/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.deployer/org.apache.karaf.deployer.features/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.deployer/org.apache.karaf.deployer.kar/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.deployer/org.apache.karaf.deployer.wrap/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.diagnostic/org.apache.karaf.diagnostic.core/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/org.apache.karaf.features.command/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.http/org.apache.karaf.http.core/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.instance/org.apache.karaf.instance.core/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.jaas.blueprint/.../4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.jaas/org.apache.karaf.jaas.command/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.jaas/org.apache.karaf.jaas.config/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.jaas/org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.kar/org.apache.karaf.kar.core/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.log/org.apache.karaf.log.core/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.management/org.apache.karaf.management.server/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.maven/org.apache.karaf.maven.core/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.package/org.apache.karaf.package.core/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.scr/org.apache.karaf.scr.management/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.scr/org.apache.karaf.scr.state/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.service/org.apache.karaf.service.core/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.shell/org.apache.karaf.shell.aesh-jline/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.shell/org.apache.karaf.shell.commands/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.shell/org.apache.karaf.shell.core/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.shell/org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.system/org.apache.karaf.system.core/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.karaf.web/org.apache.karaf.web.core/4.4.3.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.mina/mina-core/2.0.21
mvn:org.apache.neethi/neethi/3.1.1.redhat-1
mvn:org.apache.santuario/xmlsec/2.1.7.redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.aopalliance/1.0.6.fuse-redhat-00006
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.bcel/5.2.4.fuse-redhat-00006
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.cglib/3.2.12.1-fuse-redhat-00002
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.fastinfoset/1.2.16.1-fuse-redhat-00006
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jasypt/1.9.3.2-fuse-redhat-00003
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.javax-inject/1.3.0.fuse-redhat-00006
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-runtime/2.3.2_3
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-xjc/2.3.2_2
wrap:mvn:com.github.mwiede/...
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.opensaml/3.3.0.2-fuse-redhat-00006
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.reflections/0.9.11.2-fuse-redhat-00006
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.rhino/1.7.7.1-fuse-redhat-00005
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.saaj-impl/1.3.23.2-fuse-redhat-00006
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop/5.3.34.1-fuse-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans/5.3.34.1-fuse-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/.../5.3.34.1-fuse-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/.../5.3.34.1-fuse-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-core/5.3.34.1-fuse-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/.../5.3.34.1-fuse-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jdbc/5.3.34.1-fuse-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms/5.3.34.1-fuse-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-tx/5.3.34.1-fuse-redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.wsdl4j/1.6.3.1-fuse-redhat-00006
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xalan/2.7.2.3-fuse-redhat-00006
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlresolver/1.2.5.fuse-redhat-00006
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.specs/org.apache.servicemix.specs.javax-el-api-3.0.0/3.0.0_1
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.specs/org.apache.servicemix.specs.jaxrs-api-2.1/2.9.1
mvn:org.apache.sshd/sshd-osgi/2.12.1.redhat-00002
mvn:org.apache.sshd/sshd-scp/2.12.1.redhat-00002
mvn:org.apache.sshd/sshd-sftp/2.12.1.redhat-00002
mvn:org.apache.ws.xmlschema/xmlschema-core/2.2.5.redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.wss4j/wss4j-bindings/2.2.6.redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.wss4j/wss4j-policy/2.2.6.redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.wss4j/wss4j-ws-security-common/2.2.6.redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.wss4j/wss4j-ws-security-dom/2.2.6.redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.wss4j/wss4j-ws-security-policy-stax/2.2.6.redhat-00001
mvn:org.apache.wss4j/wss4j-ws-security-stax/2.2.6.redhat-00001
mvn:org.codehaus.jettison/jettison/1.4.1
mvn:org.eclipse.jdt/ecj/3.26.0
mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-client/9.4.54.v20240208
mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-continuation/9.4.54.v20240208
mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-http/9.4.54.v20240208
mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-io/9.4.54.v20240208
mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-jaas/9.4.54.v20240208
mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-jmx/9.4.54.v20240208
mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-security/9.4.54.v20240208
mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server/9.4.54.v20240208
mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-servlet/9.4.54.v20240208
mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-servlets/9.4.54.v20240208
mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util/9.4.54.v20240208
mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util-ajax/9.4.54.v20240208
mvn:org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/websocket-api/9.4.54.v20240208
mvn:org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/websocket-client/9.4.54.v20240208
mvn:org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/websocket-common/9.4.54.v20240208
mvn:org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/javax-websocket-client-impl/9.4.54.v20240208
mvn:org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/javax-websocket-server-impl/9.4.54.v20240208
mvn:org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/websocket-server/9.4.54.v20240208
mvn:org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/websocket-servlet/9.4.54.v20240208
mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-xml/9.4.54.v20240208
mvn:org.fusesource/activemq-client/7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00013-redhat-00001
mvn:org.jboss.fuse.modules/fuse-credential-store-commands/7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.jboss.fuse.modules/fuse-el2-compatibility/7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.jboss.fuse.modules.patch/patch-commands/7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.jboss.fuse.modules.patch/patch-core/7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.jboss.fuse.modules.patch/patch-core-api/7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001
mvn:org.jboss.xnio/xnio-api/3.8.7.SP1-redhat-00001
mvn:org.jboss.xnio/xnio-nio/3.8.7.SP1-redhat-00001
mvn:org.jline/jline-builtins/3.21.0.redhat-00001
mvn:org.jline/jline-console/3.21.0.redhat-00001
mvn:org.jline/jline-terminal/3.21.0.redhat-00001
mvn:org.jvnet.staxex/stax-ex/1.7.6
mvn:org.ow2.asm/asm/9.5
mvn:org.ow2.asm/asm-commons/9.5
mvn:org.ow2.asm/asm-tree/9.5
mvn:org.ow2.asm/asm-analysis/9.5
mvn:org.ow2.asm/asm-util/9.5
mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc-pool-common/1.5.5
mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc-pool-narayana/1.5.5
mvn:org.ops4j.pax.transx/pax-transx-tm-api/0.5.3
mvn:org.ops4j.pax.url/pax-url-classpath/2.6.14
mvn:org.ops4j.pax.url/pax-url-war/2.6.14/jar/uber
mvn:org.ops4j.pax.web/pax-web-api/8.0.26
mvn:org.ops4j.pax.web/pax-web-compatibility-servlet31/8.0.26
mvn:org.ops4j.pax.web/pax-web-deployer/8.0.26
mvn:org.ops4j.pax.web/pax-web-extender-war/8.0.26
mvn:org.ops4j.pax.web/pax-web-extender-whiteboard/8.0.26
mvn:org.ops4j.pax.web/pax-web-jsp/8.0.26
mvn:org.ops4j.pax.web/pax-web-karaf/8.0.26
mvn:org.ops4j.pax.web/pax-web-runtime/8.0.26
mvn:org.ops4j.pax.web/pax-web-spi/8.0.26
mvn:org.ops4j.pax.web/pax-web-tomcat-common/8.0.26
mvn:org.ops4j.pax.web/pax-web-undertow/8.0.26
mvn:org.ops4j.pax.web/pax-web-undertow-websocket/8.0.26
mvn:org.ops4j.pax.web/pax-web-websocket/8.0.26
mvn:org.osgi/org.osgi.service.component/1.5.0
mvn:org.osgi/org.osgi.service.jdbc/1.0.1
mvn:org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.33.0.redhat-00002
mvn:org.codehaus.woodstox/stax2-api/4.2.1
mvn:org.apache.aries.tx-control/tx-control-service-local/1.0.1
mvn:org.apache.aries.tx-control/tx-control-service-xa/1.0.1
wrap:mvn:io.apicurio/apicurio-data-models/1.0.16.Final-redhat-00001
wrap:mvn:io.swagger/swagger-parser/1.0.52
wrap:mvn:org.jacorb/jacorb-omgapi/3.7
wrap:mvn:org.jdom/jdom2/2.0.6.1-redhat-00001
wrap:file:/.../deploy/ezmorph-1.0.3.jar$Bundle-SymbolicName=ezmorph&Bundle-Version=1.0.3
file:/.../fuse-karaf-7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001/deploy/commons-beanutils-1.9.2.redhat-1.jar
wrap:file:/.../deploy/dom4j-1.6.1.jar$Bundle-SymbolicName=dom4j&Bundle-Version=1.6.1
wrap:file:/...
wrap:file:/.../deploy/fastjson-1.2.4.jar$Bundle-SymbolicName=fastjson&Bundle-Version=1.2.4
wrap:file:/.../deploy/json-lib-2.1-jdk15.jar$Bundle-SymbolicName=json-lib&Bundle-Version=2.1.0.jdk15
wrap:file:/.../deploy/staxon-1.2.jar$Bundle-SymbolicName=staxon&Bundle-Version=1.2
wrap:jardir:D:\fuse-karaf-7.13.0\fuse-karaf-7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001\deploy\starxsd$Bundle-SymbolicName=D:\fuse-karaf&Bundle-Version=7.13.0.fuse-karaf-7130/...
wrap:file:/.../deploy/httpclient-4.5.2.jar$Bundle-SymbolicName=httpclient&Bundle-Version=4.5.2
file:/D:/fuse-karaf-7.13.0/fuse-karaf-7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001/deploy/ion-java-1.0.2.jar
wrap:file:/...
file:/D:/fuse-karaf-7.13.0/fuse-karaf-7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001/deploy/jettison-1.2.jar
wrap:file:/.../jmespath-java-1.11.506.jar$Bundle-SymbolicName=jmespath-java&Bundle-Version=1.11.506
file:/.../deploy/commons-compress-1.26.0.redhat-00002.jar
file:/.../fuse-karaf-7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001/deploy/jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.6.7.jar
file:/D:/fuse-karaf-7.13.0/fuse-karaf-7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001/deploy/jaxen-1.1.6.jar
file:/.../fuse-karaf-7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001/deploy/jackson-annotations-2.4.0.jar
file:/.../deploy/commons-logging-1.2.0.redhat-00012.jar
file:/.../fuse-karaf-7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001/deploy/commons-lang-2.6.0.redhat-00008.jar
file:/.../fuse-karaf-7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001/deploy/commons-jxpath-1.3.jar
file:/.../fuse-karaf-7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001/deploy/commons-codec-1.8.jar
wrap:file:/.../deploy/servlet-api-2.4.jar$Bundle-SymbolicName=servlet-api&Bundle-Version=2.4
file:/D:/fuse-karaf-7.13.0/fuse-karaf-7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001/deploy/xom-1.2.5.jar
wrap:file:/.../deploy/jdom-1.1.jar$Bundle-SymbolicName=jdom&Bundle-Version=1.1
file:/.../deploy/commons-collections-3.2.2.redhat-2.jar
file:/.../fuse-karaf-7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001/deploy/commons-io-2.15.1.redhat-00001.jar
wrap:file:/.../deploy/org.restlet-2.3.12.jar$Bundle-SymbolicName=org.restlet&Bundle-Version=2.3.12
file:/.../deploy/org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common-0.31.jar
file:/.../deploy/org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client-0.31.jar
file:/.../fuse-karaf-7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001/deploy/jackson-core-2.4.1.jar
file:/.../fuse-karaf-7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001/deploy/jackson-databind-2.4.1.jar
wrap:file:/...
wrap:file:/.../deploy/httpcore-4.4.4.jar$Bundle-SymbolicName=httpcore&Bundle-Version=4.4.4
file:/.../fuse-karaf-7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001/deploy/commons-fileupload-1.5.jar
file:/D:/fuse-karaf-7.13.0/fuse-karaf-7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001/deploy/joda-time-2.8.1.jar


Spring DM was deprecated even in Fuse 6.2.

aries-blueprint-spring is not production-grade feature, because it doesn't translate everything that can be done with Spring DM XMLs. Please attach list of installed bundles (la -l in Karaf console) - did you use deploy/ directory to install the bundles?

@GrzegorzGrzybek I agree "aries-blueprint-spring" is not recommended, Since it is a legacy application , I am giving it a try. I doubt if I convert this to blueprint ftp route will work or not. I have added la -l output and I am using deploy/ directory.

You see that you have both mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.12.6.redhat-00001 and file:/.../fuse-karaf-7.13.0.fuse-7_13_0-00012-redhat-00001/deploy/jackson-core-2.4.1.jar? You see - the problem is that if you pollute deploy/ directory, you simply get lots of OSGi wiring problems. This is NOT a folder for deploying your application - this is for tests only.
Camel FTP component is one of the most important ones that undergoes extensive QA process. So please start with cleaning up this folder, And checking documentation.

https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_fuse/7.13/html/deploying_into_apache_karaf/deployfeatures

@GrzegorzGrzybek Thank you , I will try to clean up the deploy folder
